# underoverlap: draw overlapping boxes around text/math?

Tags: box, overlap

I am trying to have overlapping boxes over a sequence of signs. Basically, in ABCDE I would have SB, BC, CD, etc. I tried with the `underoverlap` package, which has a code snippet for some overlapping boxes. I am not able to get correct spacing with this, see code below. But anyway, maybe there are some easier solutions with other functions? An ideal solution would have boxes with different colors/shapes to make the overlap less crowded.

Thanks!

```
\usepackage{underoverlap}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newUOLdecorator\UOLfbox{{%
    \fboxsep=1.2pt\fboxrule=.8pt%
    \kern-\fboxrule \kern-\fboxsep%
    \fbox{$#1$}%
    \kern-\fboxsep  \kern-\fboxrule%
}}

\newUOLdecorator\UOLfboxx{{%
    \fboxsep=1.2pt\fboxrule=.5pt%
    \kern-\fboxrule \kern-\fboxsep%
    {\color{red}
    \fbox{\color{red}$#1$}}%
    \kern-\fboxsep  \kern-\fboxrule%
}}
```

Then code:

```
$\UOLfbox{b}[ d]\UOLfboxx{e} $

$\UOLfbox{\phantom{b} b}[ d\phantom{b}]\UOLfboxx{\phantom{b} e} $

$\UOLfbox{\phantom{b} b}[\phantom{b} d]\UOLfboxx{\phantom{b} e} $

$\UOLfbox{\quad b}[\quad d]\UOLfboxx{\quad e} $
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please draw an approximate version of what you'd like to get?

Comment: Mmh, that'a little difficult, but basically I hope spacing is good enough so that the red box starts between b and d, not on b?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inserting spaces in the right places using e.g. `\;` or `\quad` it looks better. You'll just have to play around with the [different math space commands](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Spacing_in_math_mode). It seems you need a space after the `b` and before the `e` to make it space it correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{underoverlap}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newUOLdecorator\UOLfbox{{%
    \fboxsep=1.2pt\fboxrule=.8pt%
    \kern-\fboxrule \kern-\fboxsep%
    \fbox{$#1$}%
    \kern-\fboxsep  \kern-\fboxrule%
}}
\newUOLdecorator\UOLfboxx{{%
    \fboxsep=1.2pt\fboxrule=.5pt%
    \kern-\fboxrule \kern-\fboxsep%
    {\color{red}
    \fbox{\color{red}$#1$}}%
    \kern-\fboxsep  \kern-\fboxrule%
}}
\begin{document}
    $\UOLfbox{b\;}[d]\UOLfboxx{\;e} $
    $\UOLfbox{\phantom{b} b\;}[ d\phantom{b}]\UOLfboxx{\phantom{b} e} $
    $\UOLfbox{\phantom{b} b\;}[\phantom{b} d]\UOLfboxx{\phantom{b} e} $
    $\UOLfbox{\quad b\;}[\quad d]\UOLfboxx{\quad e} $
    $\UOLfbox{b\quad}[d]\UOLfboxx{\quad e}$
    $\quad\UOLfbox{b\quad}[d]\UOLfboxx{\qquad e}$
\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the latex code above]

Comment: great, thanks!!